# open file path produced from combined variables fails

Tags: unix

I'm trying open the latest file in a folder from a path produced by combining variables, but I get 'file does not exist':

```
FileFolder="/Users/Shared/FaxesCopy/"
# get latest file in folder
LatestFile=`ls -t $FileFolder | head -1`
# replace non-recognizable characters
LatestFile=$(echo $LatestFile|sed 's/ /\\ /g')
LatestFile=$(echo $LatestFile|sed 's/(/\\(/g')
LatestFile=$(echo $LatestFile|sed 's/)/\\)/g')
# combine variables 
FullAdd="${FileFolder}${LatestFile}"
# ensure address is valid
echo $FullAdd
open "$FullAdd"
```

Puzzled?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already quoting `$FullAdd` when you use it (which you should), any manual escaping you might do is going to be interpreted as literal characters in the name of the file.  Just delete the substitutions and you should be fine.